# Redirect HTTP requests based on subdomain address without changing accessed URL?

Tags: apache-2.2, http, .htaccess

Let's say I have a domain, *www.mydomain.com*.
And I ordered a new domain,  *abc.newdomain.com*.

Both domains are hosted in the same ISP, so currently requests to either of those addresses result in the same page being shown.

I want to redirect all requests to abc.newdomain.com to folder /wp so that when users access abc.newdomain.com they would see whatever is inside folder /wp without seeing the URL change.

Questions:

1. How can I achieve this using .htaccess?
2. How can I prevent users from accessing directly /wp directory (meaning that www.mydomain.com/wp would be blocked)?

Answer (score 0):

[`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) can do both of those.

For the first, check the host with `RewriteCond` and write a rule to rewrite it without using the `R` flag.

For the second, check the host for `www.mydomain.com` and write a rule that rewrites anything back to itself with a `R=404` flag.